# How to sort NSMutableOrderedSet alphabetically?

Tags: objective-c

I want to sort an NSMutableOrderedSet of strings, alphabetically.  Is there a method?  I've searched but can't find any.

Looking for something like this if it was an array:

```
sortedArray = [originalArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector
 (localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[nameOfSet sortUsingComparator:(NSComparator)^(id obj1, id obj2){
    return [obj1 localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:obj2]; }];
}
```

Comment: You can sort a set? That's strange, indeed.

Comment: @H2CO3 I know, I'm somewhat confused by what an "ordered set" is supposed to be.

Comment: yeah, Apple changes math... :P

Comment: Thanks for the example. It popped up in Xcode I think but I didn't know how to use as I haven't used blocks much.  Just to note it gave an error though if the result is assigned, because the return is void, but works fine just used by itself.

Answer (score 0):

Use `localizedStandardCompare` instead of `localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare`, suppose you want 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ...., 100 or more, then after 9 `localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare` is not able to sort your set, it will print like 1,10,2... etc. but `localizedStandardCompare` will sort accurately.

```
[nameOfSet sortUsingComparator:(NSComparator)^(id obj1, id obj2){
        return [obj1 localizedStandardCompare:obj2]; }];
```

Thanks